# template suggestion not working (page--front.tpl.php) in windows 7 env

Tags: 7, theming

I do my development in a windows 7 env. Using XAMPP to run D7 and supporting apps.

I am giving the template suggestion of `page--front.tpl.php` for my D7 theme. For whatever reason the file doesn't seem to be getting recognized by D7. I pushed my code to my development server (linux) and `page--front.tpl.php` is picked up without issue.

has anyone seen this behavior? I can't lock down what is happening here.

Comment: Is it possible you've cleared the cache on the linux version but not the windows version? The new file won't get picked up until that's done

Comment: cleared all cache. still no go. also threw the keyboard at my pc. still won't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen when there is another `page--front.tpl.php` lurking around in your directory structure and it is being picked up and used instead of the one you are looking at.  And, if that one is a copy of `page.tpl.php`, it will *appear* that it isn't being picked up. So, I'd look around and make sure you don't have one anywhere in your theme directory as Drupal will recurse through the entire tree looking for templates.  Another edge case is permissions so make sure it is readable to the world.  If all else fails, strangling the pc with the mouse brings some level of relief and entertainment :)

Comment: i'll mark this as resolved because what you said simply gave me the "are you kidding me?" moment. basically the default home page was not set properly which makes no sense to me since i'm positive i set it. when i navigated to the home page, the right node was displayed (just not registered as front page). when i re-added `home` to the default home page it all worked. anyway, thanks.

Comment: ps -- your 732 site looks great.  brings back memories.  when I lived there it was still 201 :)

Comment: and just because i wasted 30mins on this, i took the mouse to the pc... it would appear sheet metal is stronger then 30awg wire.

Comment: thanks. that was my first ever drupal build (D6). lots of keyboard throwing on that project! i need to migrate it to D7 in the worst way. however, this particular project is for my day job which again is a D6 to D7 migration. Can't wait to re-write my custom mods.